# Change id of a Table row using javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hello I have a table which has a few rows. And I have an add button in my application which allows to add rows at any rowIndex. I use insertRow method to insert rows at a specific position. So once a row in inserted, I change the table row Ids of all the rows, to arrange them in an ascending order. Now I have been developing this application in FF and it has been coming pretty well. Now I am making a few changes to the code to make it work in IE. But this just does not work in IE. I have been testing this code for the last two days, it works in FF and chrome, but not in IE. I am not sure, what is the mistake I am making. I am just recreating the situation with an example, and this is the code for that example. Please help me out and tell me what could be the mistake I am making for it not to be working in IE. Any suggestions would be a great help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function getIds()
{
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for(var i in elem)
 {
 if(elem[i] && elem[i].id!=null && elem[i].id!='')
 alert(elem[i].id);
 }
}

function changeIds()
{
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for(var i in elem)
 {
 if(elem[i] && elem[i].id!=null && elem[i].id!='')
 { index = Number(elem[i].rowIndex)+1; elem[i].id = "tabsf_"+index;} 

 }
 alert('change');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tabsf">
 <tbody>
  <tr id="tabsf_1"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_2"><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_5"><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_3"><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_4"><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table><tr><td><input type="button" name="hach" value="getIds" onclick="getIds()" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="hach" value="Change Ids" onclick="changeIds()" /></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

Comment: Can you format the code? I would if I could edit.

Comment: I am a complete newbie, I do not know how to format it? any help with that?

Comment: @Sai select the text and click the "01010101" button in the edit field. I did it for you already though.

Comment: <table id="tabsf">
 <tbody>
  <tr id="tabsf_1"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_2"><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_5"><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_3"><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr id="tabsf_4"><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

Comment: Thanks pekka! That is my table, and all I am trying to do is get those row Ids which are in order of 1,2,5,3,4 and get them into ascending order 1,2,3,4,5. My javascript works with FF but not with IE. I am not able to understand what the problem could be?

Comment: Can I ask how you know this is working in other browsers and not IE? What is it specifically that is happening? I am surprised if this is working in any because I am seeing the id collision like @Pekka mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Well I have three browsers presently. I am using FF, Chrome and IE. It is working in FF and Chrome, it gives me an order of 1,2,3,4 and 5 but in IE it is giving me 1,2,3,3,5. I am unable to understand why this is happening like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **for..in loop doesn't ensure order**. It is one of the [gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154215/what-are-the-most-common-causes-of-errors-in-javascript-and-how-to-fix-them/3154285#3154285) why you should **avoid them for arrays**. (there is another, see my link)
**Use simple for loops** instead ( for i..n )

```
function getIds() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].id) {
      alert(elem[i].id);
    }
  }
}

function changeIds() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].id) {
      index = Number(elem[i].rowIndex) + 1;
      elem[i].id = "tabsf_" + index;
    }
  }
  alert('change');
}
```

Works perfectly cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Try @Spinon's idea first.

**Update:** It seems to in fact have been an ID collision, something IE rightly prevented from happening and the other browsers happily let through.

**Original answer:**

My guess is that your loop creates an `id` collision: An `id` is set twice while the loop runs. IE could (rightly) be blocking the setting of a duplicate ID.

I would try unsetting the IDs first:

```
for(var i in elem)
 {

 if(elem[i] && elem[i].id!=null && elem[i].id!='')
  elem[i].id =  elem[i].id + "_temp";    
 }


for(var i in elem)
 {
 if(elem[i] && elem[i].id!=null && elem[i].id!='')
 { index = Number(elem[i].rowIndex)+1; 
   elem[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML = "tabsf_"+index;    
   elem[i].id = "tabsf_"+index;} 

 }
```

However, I don't understand how you use row IDs to change the sorting?

Comment: Well these rows have child elements which have the required data. On a PHP submit, I get all elements in each row, get the data in them and post them to my database. The data is arranged based on these row IDs.

Comment: But when I do that it says 'undefined' is null or not an object. So I tried to setAttribute for that element using elem[i].id = null;elem[i].setAttribute("id", "tabsf_"+index);

But it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @sai my bad, sorry. I changed the mechanism a bit and added a check.

Comment: it is giving me the same undefined is null or not an object error :(

Comment: @sai I haven't tested it, I'll do that now.

Comment: That will be a great help Sir. Thanks!

Comment: @sai the version I posted works for me. Can you try again? I added a line that shows the sorting effect immediately, just remove that for real world use.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir!! you are the man!! but I still wonder why was it working in other browsers :| and why is IE so complex??

Comment: @sai if this was the problem, IE is the one that got it right: The other browsers are overly tolerant. A duplicate ID leads to that element not being able to be loaded using `getElementById` anymore, something that the other browsers should prevent.

Comment: Ok! I guess this surely is my lesson to learn then!! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I would say try using the setAttribute function vs the id property to change the id.

Comment: Hello Spion I used setAttribute function elem[i].setAttribute("id", "tabsf_"+index); The wierd thing that happened was row Ids were changed in this way 1,2,3,3,5. What could this mean?? It should have been 1,2,3,4,5. I am using IE developer tools to view the dom and that shows the rowIds